# Translate java Logical Operator into R

Tags: java, r, logic

I need to convert this `java` statement into `R` (simplified):

```
return T/F || T/F || T/F ^ T/F;
```

I see that `^` is the "bitwise exclusive OR" in `java`, but I'm don't completely understand what this would be in `R`. It sort of sounds like one or the other of the last two terms must be `TRUE`, but that's just a guess.  I'd appreciate a clue so that I get the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Check my new answer I was wrong with the parenthesis, but now its fixed... let me know if it worked.

Comment: This would be a better question if you told us what kind of thing T and F (integer? boolean?) were, included a runnable Java example and showed examples of output given values of T and F.

Comment: @Spacedman I understand your point, but I was trying to port java to R and I don't really know java (but was successful).  The actual T/F statements were derived from a bunch of one-off code and wouldn't have been useful here.  Not knowing java, I didn't want to write a MRE/MWE and substitute expressions like if(today is tuesday) for T/F.  So I went with a conceptual expression instead.

Comment: Trying to port something you can't run to test if the behaviour is correct is not a good thing to do. With an object-oriented language, you never can tell what any operator does without knowing what class the things operated on are. Context is everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "bitwise exclusive OR" in `R` is `xor(x,y)`, look in the documentation [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Logic.html).
You should use parenthesis when you use different operators... but basically:

`return T/F || T/F || (T/F ^ T/F);` in `java`

means:

`return(T/F || T/F || xor(T/F, T/F))` in `R`

or maybe that is not the order of precedence that you have in mind... if is not, I can help you if you use parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you @Balz... I copied that java code just as I found it, no parens, which added to my concern and confusion.  In your java code above, did you place the parens where the operator precedence rules would put them if my example were parsed?  Probably.  But I just wanted to check.

Comment: According to this [page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html) (which it's not a bad reference) the precedence goes: 1) AND, 2) XOR, 3) OR.

So the **new** java code (has been modified) has the operators precedence rules.

Comment: Thanks!  The revised way is a bit more like I imagined it.  The original version seemed to work, I'll try the new one too.

Comment: Yes, that edit was important, so a big thanks!  I was not getting errors with the original, but the revised version appears to be giving the expected answers.